# how to get data from database to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sqlite

I iam trying to fetch data from database to listview.i have to tables in my dbhelper class.
one is login data table and other one is data storing table. From that table iam fetching data   to listview. please find my code here and tell me what is problem here. my log cat shows nullpoint exception at the getAllValues() method. please help me.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sri.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
   "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
   "username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String DB_ADMIN = "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME+"values(1, admin,                 password);";

public static final String TABLE_NAME_SAVE="saveinfo";
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
public static final String KEY_URL="surl";
public static final String KEY_UID="suid";
public static final String KEY_PASS="spassword";

public static final String SCRIPT="CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME_SAVE + "(" + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
"surl TEXT NOT NULL, suid TEXT NOT NULL, spassword TEXT NOT NULL);";



public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("In constructor");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        //Create Database
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        //create admin account
        db.execSQL(DB_ADMIN);
        //System.out.println("In onCreate");
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }



}


     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    onCreate(db);

}
       SQLiteDatabase db;

   public Cursor getAllValues() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] clumns={KEY_ID,KEY_URL,KEY_UID,KEY_PASS};
return db.query(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, clumns, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

   void deleteAllRecords(){
  db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, null, null);
 }




 void deleteOneRecord(String rowid){
  db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, rowid +"="+KEY_ID, null);
 }

public void openDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



 }
```

here is my **DbHelper** calss

here is my **DisplayActivity**.java calss

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity implements OnItemLongClickListener {

DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
Cursor cursor;
ListView list;
private int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    db.openDatabase();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvf);

     //updateListView();
      list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
}



class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return cursor.getCount();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details, null);

       TextView t0 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.did);
       TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.durl);
       TextView t2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duid);
       TextView t3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dpass);

       cursor.moveToPosition(position);

       String rowid = cursor.getString(0);
       String url = cursor.getString(1);
       String uid = cursor.getString(2);
       String pass=cursor.getString(3);

       t0.setText(rowid);
       t1.setText(url);
       t2.setText(uid);
       t3.setText(pass);
       return view;
      }

     }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
    return true;
}
void updateListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cursor = db.getAllValues();
      CustomAdapter cs = new CustomAdapter();
      list.setAdapter(cs);


}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.position=pos;
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use cursor adapter see the example below:

```
public class ContactCursorAdapterCT extends CursorAdapter {
       public ContactCursorAdapterCT(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.blacklistDB1);               
          name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
          (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));

          TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.blacklistDB2); 
          phone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
          (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

}
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv, parent, false);
            bindView(v, context, cursor);
           return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized your `db` in your `DbHelper` method. Drop it from the class field, it's not needed there. You should init it like the following at your `getAllValues()` method:

```
public Cursor getAllValues() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] clumns={KEY_ID,KEY_URL,KEY_UID,KEY_PASS};
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME_SAVE, clumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

}

BTW, it's better to use a singleton for `SQLiteOpenHelper`. In such a case you can get database in all your method just by `SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();